# How to merge two PDF pages to a single page?

Tags: pdf, merge, concatenation

I have two PDF files (`1.pdf` and `2.pdf`), each containing a single page with a graph. I want to generate a third file (`both_on_a_single_page.pdf`), that shows the two graphs next to each other **on a single page**.

In `pdftk` I was only able to concatenate the files into one file with 2 pages. Opening the files with `gimp` changed the symbols of the graphs,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[pdfjam](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/statistics/staff/academic-research/firth/software/pdfjam/) or `pdfnup` (included in `pdfjam`) should work for you.

> `pdfnup`, which allows one or more PDF files to be "n-upped" in roughly
>   the way that `psnup` does for PostScript files. (This was the original
>   motivation: for files that have to be printed, or have to be made
>   available to dozens or hundreds of other people for printing, n-up
>   formatting saves trees!)